# Parsing date and time string into a number to compare C++

Tags: c++, parsing, epoch, time.h

My application receives a date and time string. I need to be able to parse this string and compare it to the current time in seconds.

I am parsing this as below into a `struct tm t` to get the year, month, day, hour, minute, and second separately.

```
    std::string timestr = "2020-12-18T16:40:07";
    struct tm t = {0};

    sscanf(timestr.c_str(), "%04d-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:%02d",
           &t.tm_year, &t.tm_mon,  &t.tm_mday,
           &t.tm_hour, &t.tm_min, &t.tm_sec);
```

I'm not sure if I need to convert this to epoch time, but when I do , I get -1. I'm not sure why.

```
time_t t_of_day;
t_of_day = mktime(&t);
```

Do I actually need to convert this to epoch first?

What is the best way for me to get the current time in seconds and then compare it to the time information I get in `t`? Thanks.

Comment: Does that string represent UTC or some local time zone?  If a time zone, which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want C++ parsing:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time

```
std::stringstream timestr = "2020-12-18T16:40:07";
struct tm         t = {0};

timestr >> std::get_time(&t, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S");
```

I should note there is a bug in your code as: `tm_year` is not the same as year as we know it. This is the number of years since 1900!

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/

So your code needs another line:

```
 t.tm_year -= 1900;
```

Note: `std::get_time()` already does that compensation.

This is probably why `mktime()` is returning -1 as the year 3920 is out of range.

Comment: Are you sure t.tm_year -= 1900; is required ?  It shows 2020 for me when I print it out even without subtraction

Answer (score 3):

Just use the features of `chrono` library:

```cpp
auto tp    = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&t));
auto epoch = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(tp.time_since_epoch());
```

but you don't need to convert it to epoch. Use `std::chrono::time_point` comparison like:

```cpp
auto tp    = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&t));
auto now   = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

std::cout << (tp == now) << std::endl;
```